# How to concatenate two strings and add the result to the end of a line in python

Tags: python

I have a file containing tab delimited strings...

```
string_one    string_two
```

I want to take the file as input and return it with a new tab delimited value at the end of each line which contains the concatenation of the two strings.

So far I have this

```
#concatenate.py

from sys import argv

scriptname, filename = argv

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        #take the first word
        #take the second word
        #concatenate them and add them to the end of line
```

I've tried

```
for word in line
```

to get each word but it gets each character, how do I specify (tokenize) each word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` and `join` like this

```
with open("Input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line, "".join(line.split()[:2])
```

This will print

```
string_one    string_two string_onestring_two
```

**Edit:** If the file is not huge, you can do this

```
lines = []
with open("Input.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("Input.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        f.write(line + "".join(line.split()[:2]) + "\n")
```

Comment: how would I write this back to the file instead of printing it?

Comment: @Luke Are you seriously asking this? Can you not Google 'python write to file'?

Comment: @vape passing the call to open the 'w' arguement and using f.write results in an error for me, saying the file is not opened for reading.

Answer (score 1):

To split string into words you can use string's [split method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
'To split string into words you can use string\'s split method'.split() # returns ['To', 'split', 'string', 'into', 'words', 'you', 'can', 'use', "string's", 'split', 'method']
```

To concatenate use can use `+`, or [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
line = 'one ' + 'two' # line is 'one two' 
line = ' '.join(['one', 'two']) # line is 'one two'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = line.strip() + '\t' + ''.join(line.split())
```